# Как сделать соединение двух сложных селектов

Tags: sql, sql-server

Два таких запроса соединить через join

```
 declare @Year char(4) = '2013'


select 
    Year
    ,sForms.IdForm
    ,ShForm
    ,NForm
from sForms
JOIN dbo.tRepForms rep 
            ON rep.IdForm = sForms.IdForm
where sForms.Year = @Year and OP = 0 and rep.IdReport = 1
union
select
    @Year as Year
    ,'000'
    ,'ГО'
    ,'Годовой отчет'

--*******  JOIN ON IdForm  ****************
select
     IdForm
    ,IdTable
    ,ShTable
    ,ISNULL(NTable,'') as NTable
from sTabs
where Year = @Year
union
select
    IdForm
    ,'00000'
    ,'ЛП'
    ,'Лист подписей'
from sTabs where Year = @Year
union 
select
    '000'
    ,'00000'
    ,'ЛП'
    ,'Общий лист подписей'
```

Может вообще нужно что-то по другому писать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select *
from 
( первый сложный селект ) as s1
left join 
( второй сложный селект) as s2
on s1.IdForm = s2.IdForm
```